# RelativeLayout with background image scales incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have one `RelativeLayout` with a background image. Inside it, I have another `RelativeLayout` with a background color. I want the second `RelativeLayout` be in the middle of the first one, but it gets wrong scales depending on the screen size.

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cellphone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cellphone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cellphone_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:background="#e34579">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of a large screen device: 
[image: Nexus 6 - 6", 1440 x 2560: 560dpi]

Screenshot of the same code, but of a small screen device:

[image: Nexus One - 3.7", 480 x 800: hdpi]

As you can see, the yellow border should not be visible.

How can I fix it?

P.S.: I have the background image (cellphone.png) in all sizes (from drawable-ldpi to drawable-xxxhdpi).

**EDIT:**

The *cellphone.png* image in xxhdpi:

[image]

Comment: can you provide particular image?

Comment: Please show cellphone.png

Comment: @RishiPaul, here's the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage margins according to device using dimens.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cellphone_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
            android:background="#e34579">

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing Margins from your Main RalativeLayout

```
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeft"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
```